# creating a common oracle database connection using a single form c# for several forms

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, connection

I have created an oracle database connection in one form(Form1) and used the same connection in another form(Form2) to retrieve some data from the database!.But I get an error unhandled exception when trying to retrieve data onto a label in the second form!

The code of form1 is as follows(It is working properly!)

```
 public void connection()
        {
            con = new OracleConnection("Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST ="+ip.Text+")(PORT ="+port.Text+"))) " +
            " (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = SHARED) (SERVICE_NAME = ora12c) )" +
        " ); User Id =" + uname.Text + "; password=" + pword.Text);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection();
            con.Open();

                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();


        }
```

The code in the second form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.connection();
            f1.con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select name from username";
            cmd.Connection = f1.con;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        }
```

When I enter the details(username,password,etc) and click the lgin button in form1 I get access to form2 but in form2 when I click the load button I geth the error 
`"An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll"`
highlighting f1.con.Open();

Comment: Not much point telling us the Type of the Exception, telling us the .Message property value would be more useful..

Comment: I get "Additional information: Connection must be open for this operation"

Comment: Why can't you use the separate connection of Form2 it own?

Comment: Ps; for what it's worth, nearly nothing about this code or the question is the way it should be done - you say you're trying to make a common connection on a single form, but you have two forms, you recreate rather than recycle the connection, you never close it, nor do you close/dispose of your readers and correctly designed programs never have database access code in their button click handlers. Following a good tutorial talking about modern database access methods (nhibernate, entity framework, datasets/tableadapters) would be the best thing you can do right now; throw this code away

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I get user name and the relevant details from Form1! So I have to use the connection created in Form1 for Form2

Comment: Try removing`connection();` and `con.Open();` in `button1_Click` in Form1.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanx but I get the same error! :(

Comment: Got it.. the issue is different here... Since you are doing `Form1 f1 = new Form1();` the connection string generated in `f1.connection();` will not have proper values of UserId, Password, HOST etc because `f1` is a new instance of `Form1` so text boxes of it will be blank. You need to make sure that the values entered in the `Form1` at the first time should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `Form1` in `button1_Click1 of`Form2`. Due to this the connection string in`f1.connection1`is generated using blank values of the text boxes of`Form1`.

To resolve this issue you need to make sure that the connection which is created in `Form1.connection` method should be stored somewhere so that you can use the same connection in `Form2` also.

Consider having a helper class which maintains the connection object as a static object inside it. Which you can set at one place and retrieve it at other place.

```
public static class DatabaseHelper
{
    private static OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    private static string connectionStringTemplate = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST ={0})(PORT ={1}))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = SHARED) (SERVICE_NAME = ora12c) ) ); User Id ={2}; password={3}";

    public static void SetConnection(string ipAddress, string portNumber, string userName, string password)
    {
        var connectionString = string.Format(connectionStringTemplate, ipAddress, portNumber, userName, password);

        oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public static void SetConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public static OracleConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return oracleConnection;
    }
}
```

Now you can use call `DatabaseHelper.SetConnection` method from `Form1` to set the connection.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseHelper.SetConnection(ip.Text,port.Text, uname.Text, pword.Text);
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

And retrieve and reuse the connection in Form2 as following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection con = DatabaseHelper.GetConnection();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select name from username";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanx but I get an error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."  highlighting the  OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); section

Comment: Which line of code gives error? Are you writing the code the same way I suggested? I just updated my answer. It had some obvious issues. I fixed them.

Comment: OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: What is the message of the exception? Is there any InnerException? What is the message of InnerException?